# C# - All values where ID is 1 from List

Tags: c#, linq

I got a List that contains all the employees, now I need to dig in to a specific employee on a new page. I want to get all the values from the employee where the ID is 1 for example. Is there a sollution for this in LINQ?
It's practically a Query SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE id = 1;

```
class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleOfCourtesy { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    //public Image Photo { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int ReportsTo { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
}
```

I tried it like this but it doesn't work:

```
           List<Employee> employees = Database.getEmployees();

        var uniqUsers = employees.Where(x => employees.Contains(x.EmployeeID == 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hare you look at the `Where` Linq statement?  Should be as simple as `employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeID == 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where `employee` is type of `IEnumerable<Employee>`

If you are expecting 1 record:

```
var result = employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == 1); // Returns Employee
```

If you are expecting more than 1 record:

```
var result = employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 1); // Return IEnumerable<Employee>
```

Please note, when using `FirstOrDefault` if there is no items in your collection (or doesn't match your lambda) then it will return default `T` which in your case will be `Employee` and it will be null.

Comment: this only returns the first value. The post asks for all

Comment: if you use FirstOrDefault  You have to definitely control value is null  for example   

var result = employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);
if(result != null)
{
     // Code
}

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag Correct, It depends what the OP wants. He could use First() but then there is the case of an exception being thrown. But I think he wants all of the results anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "single" item that meets that critera use the `Single` Linq statement:

```
Employee employee = employees.Single(e => e.EmployeeID == 1);
```

or

```
Employee employee = employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == 1);
```

if you want the query to  return `null` instead of throwing an exception if there is not an item in the list that meets that criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Let `EmployeeList` is the current List of Employees. You can use LINQ to filter the required details as like the specified query by using this(IT will give you all sublist satisfies the specified condition):

```
int empIdToSearch=1;
List<Employee> FilteredList=EmployeeList.Where(x=>x.EmployeeID ==empIdToSearch).ToList();
```

If the `EmployeeID` is unique then there will be one item in the list with particular ID, You can use `FirstOrDefault` to get the First item from the collection that satisfies the condition.ie.,

```
Employee EmployeeObject= FilteredList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == empIdToSearch);
```

Comment: @downvoter : care to explain the reason, that may help me to update the post to ensure the quality

Answer (score 1):

The concept that you need to get is how most linq queries operate.

When you say `.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 1)` then `x` is a single empolyee as if you said:

```
foreach(Employee x in employees)
{
   if(x.EmployeeID == 1)
     // take it
}
```

So the correct syntax would be:

`List<Employee> uniqUsers = employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 1).ToList();`

**Single Optional Result:**

`Employee uniqUser = employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);`

**Single Mandatory Result:**

`Employee uniqUser = employees.Single(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);`

**First Optional Result:**

`Employee uniqUser = employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);`

**First Mandatory Result:**

`Employee uniqUser = employees.First(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);`

Comment: Single Optional Result should use `SingleOrDefault`? Also `FindAll` will copy the actual list, where `Where` returns a lazily evaluated sequence. So `Where` will usually be faster.

Comment: @JamieR He used `Where` + `ToList()` which is equivelant to `FindAll`

Answer (score 1):

We can fetch the records from collection in two ways.

*Linq to sql like query*

```
var employee= from emp in employees where emp.ID==1;
```

*Linq to extension methods.*

```
var employee = employees.Where(emp=>emp.ID==1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq supports a query syntax that is closer to SQL.

```
var employee1 = from employee in employees where employee.EmployeeID == 1 select employee;

foreach (var x in employee1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.EmployeeID);
}
```

The compiler converts all query syntax to method syntax. Not all things can be done with query syntax. The 'from' comes before the 'select' so auto-complete is more useful. It is important to note the linq query is not executed until it is used. The foreach loop is where it is first used in this example.